# Is there a way to inspect field attributes on a related model during model loading?

Tags: django-models

Suppose I have two models, the former owned by third party code:

```py
class A(models.Model):
    x = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class B(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey("other_app.A", ...)
    name = models.CharField(...)
```

Suppose further that I'd like `B.name.max_length` to be set based on `B.a.x.max_length`.  You can imagine this to be useful for instance when denormalising fields for string representations.  Should `A` be `django.contrib.auth.get_user_model()`, and `B` be a `Profile`, `B.name` might want to read `f"Profile for {self.a.username}"`, thus setting the requirement for `B.name.max_length == A.x.max_length + len("Profile for ")`.

I could head in and inspect what the `.max_length`s on my dependencies are manually, sum them manually, and hardcode it, but that is manual work to duplicate data, which is likely to change.  Should `A.x.max_length` increase without a change in `B.name.max_length`, suddenly certain new values in the database can cause 500s.

I could set `B.name.max_length` to "something sufficiently large", but that just kicks the can down the road.  If my dependencies set a combined amount of `200`, so I set mine to `255` to be safe, my dependents and theirs and theirs have an expanding problem.

Lastly, and the reason I'm asking this, I wish I could query the related model's field's attributes and set based on that, but I seemingly can't because of Django's insistence on magic with models (and forms but that's irrelevant).

```py
class B(...):
    ...
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=a.x.field.max_length + len(PREFIX),
        ...,
    )

# AttributeError: 'ForeignKey' object has no attribute 'x'

class B(...):
    ...
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=a.related_model.x.field.max_length + len(PREFIX),
        ...,
    )

#  django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.
```

Is there any way to divine `A.x.max_length` from `B` during model loading?

I'm also quite ready to entertain the XY problem approach, so if that's the case the alternate question would be "what is the most elegant way to define `CharField.max_length` when the contents will come from another field?"

For anyone cracking open a shell to mess with this, the attribute whisks away to `A.x.field.max_length` after the Django metaclass magic involved during model loading.  To play around in the moment, I recommend setting up the models as roughly described, then running `python -i manage.py shell`, and in the interpreter `import pdb; pdb.pm()`.

Answer (score 0):

Diving into the source code I've come up with the following roundabout way to get the information from the model.

```py
from django.apps import apps

class B:
    ...
    name = models.CharField(max_length=(
        apps.get_model(
            a.remote_field.model,
            require_ready=False,
        ).x.field.max_length,
    ))
```

The main trick I found was the `require_ready` kwarg to `.get_model()`.  Without it, I get the same `Models aren't loaded yet.` exception as from `a.related_model`, which makes me think there should be/is a better way to query `ForeignKey().related_model` before models are loaded.  I'm leaving this answer unaccepted for a while pending anyone coming up with said better way.